# Не могу записать ответ webhook

Tags: php, webhook

Всем привет, извините за глупый вопрос но сам разобраться не смог.
Вообщем вот в чем дело. Webhook отправляет json массив при изменениях в базе данных.
Проверил через сайт webhook.site ,все работает хорошо. Но мне нужно принять этот массив у себя в php файле и записать его. Вот код

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST'){
    $fh = fopen("webhook.txt", 'a') or die("Ошибка");
    $data = json_encode($_POST);
    fwrite($fh, $data. PHP_EOL);
    fclose($fh);
}
?>
```

Когда Webhook отправляет запрос мне, в файле записываются просто скобки '[]'. fwrite вторым параметром принимает только строку как я понял, и я использовал implode , но в файл все равно записываются либо скобки либо пустота. А вот такой ответ получаю на сайте webhook.site

```
{
  "auditContext": {
    "meta": {
      "type": "audit",
      "href": "************"
    },
    "uid": "*****************",
    "moment": "2021-12-15 15:49:08"
  },
  "events": [
    {
      "meta": {
        "type": "product",
        "href": "************"
      },
      "updatedFields": [
        "description"
      ],
      "action": "UPDATE",
      "accountId": "*****************"
    }
  ]
}
```

Буду очень признателен если поможете) В целом мне нужно записать только ['event']['href'] , но можно и все сразу

Comment: print_r($_POST) что выдает?

Comment: @splash58 Array ( ) , он так же пишет Array ( ) , если webhook ничего не отправлял

Comment: Смотрите в сторону [php://input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28969664/receiving-webhook-data-and-save-them-in-db) вместо $_POST.

Comment: @DanielProtopopov спасибо это сработало!)